# What is exact difference between ( Accent - Dialect - Colloquial )?

Tags: meaning, word-meaning, word-difference

I know the meaning of these words but I don't know the difference between them exactly.

Would you tell me what the difference between these words is?
**Accent** - **Dialect** - **Colloquial**.

I would be thankful if you give me some examples in your answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Accent* is the way you pronounce words and sentences, so [for example] two people both speaking standard British English might speak with different accents because they use a different set of vowels, or even different intonation.  You speak a different *dialect* if your grammar or vocabulary varies significantly from another speaker's.  *Colloquial* refers to expressions that may not be regarded as standard or formal, but are in common use.